# Special number near $5^{5^3}$

Tags: number-theory, algorithms, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I search the number nearest to $5^{5^3} = 5^{125}$, which is product of two $44$-digit primes.

The direct method is :
Begin with $N = 5^{125}$. Increase $N$ until the desired number is found. Whenever a small
factor is found, the number need not to be factored completely. Do the same with
decreasing, beginning with $N$. The two found numbers have the form $N-a$ and $N+b$.
Choose the number nearer to $5^{125}$. The method is trivial, but very time-consuming.

Is there a way to find the number faster?

Comment: Presumably, you mean distinct primes.

Comment: Thomas : Yes, but a square would be too far away anyway.

Comment: 5^125+776 has very big prime factors, but unfortunately they have 43 and 45 digits. This is a near miss.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I believe the closest number to $5^{125}$ which is product of two 44-digit primes is $5^{125}-588$:

```
5^125 - 588 = 43665185956168249163369594154581467144074421 *
              53841261640441238035516896393833679276609797
```

It was found by testing the numbers $5^{125}\pm 1$, $5^{125}\pm 2$, ...; checking if they have any factor smaller than $10^9$ first and running the general-purpose factorizer on them otherwise.

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. This number was my next candidate, but I did not think that it really is the solution. Congratulations, Peter!

Comment: As you seem interested in factoring, you can also try 311#/31#+31# (C114). See question prime factors of numbers formed by primorials. You can publish the factors there.

Answer (score 1):

(This is not an answer)
There are about $8\times 10^{41}$ primes between $10^{43}$ and $10^{44}$, hence there are about $3.2\times 10^{83}$ integers of the form $pq,$ the largest one is about $10^{88}$,the least one is about $10^{86},$ the average distance is about $3\times 10^4$, so you need try about $3\times 10^4$ times to find the nearest solution.